# For a subspace $U$ of scalar product space $V$, $\dim(U^{\perp})=\dim(U^0)$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove the result in the title and would be grateful for a quick proof verification. $U^{\perp}$ is the set of all vectors in $V$ orthogonal to all vectors in $U$, and $U^0$ is the annihilator of $U$. Here's my attempt:

Let the flat map be denoted by $F$. The flat map is a map $F:V\to V^*$ such that $F(v)(w)\equiv v^F(w)=\langle v,w\rangle$. Since the bilinear function defined on $V$ is nondegenerate, $F$ is an isomorphism.

Let $w\in U^{\perp}$. Then $\langle w,u\rangle=0$ for all $u\in U$, or $w^F(u)=0$ for all $u\in U$, or $w^F\in U^0$. On the other hand, let $\eta\in U^0$ so that $\eta(u)=0$ for all $u\in U$. Since $F$ is an isomorphism, there exists a unique $w'\in V$ such that $w'^F=\eta$ and $\langle w',u\rangle=0$ for all $u\in U$, i.e., $\eta$ has a unique preimage in $U^{\perp}$.

Thus $F|_{U^{\perp}}$ is a linear isomorphism between $U^{\perp}$ and $U^0 \implies$ their dimensions are the same.

Is the above fine or are there any errors?

Comment: I haven't heard the term "flat map" for the map $F$ that you refer to. Otherwise, your proof is fine.

Comment: My bad. Flat map is a map $F:V\to V^*$ such that $F(v)(w)\equiv v^F(w)=\langle v,w\rangle$. I have edited the question to include this definition.